# What does this recursion method do?

Tags: java

This is the code that I have a problem wit understanding. I know so far that this code here passes in int a and int b. Then it checks if int b is equal to 0 and if it is then it returns 1. Then it checks if b is 1 and if so then it returns int a. But I dont get the last part of this code. Its something with recursion but I dont get it.

```
public static int mystery(int a, int b) {
if(b == 0) {
return 1;
else if(b==1) {
return a;
return a * mystery(a,b-1);
```

Comment: what have you done to attempt the problem? try your own homework first.

Answer (score 3):

This code looks like that for exponentiation where `a` is the base and `b` is the exponent. So in the case of `b = 0`, obviously, the answer would be 1 by the rules of exponentiation. When `b = 1`, then `return a` because `a ^ 1 = a`. Otherwise, use multiplication to get the result recursively where the base case for recursion is `b = 1` (`b = 0` condition will not be the base case if `b > 0`). By the way, you need to put proper parenthesis on the code for it to compile (the curly braces need to be closed).

i.e.,

```
    public static int mystery(int a, int b) {
        if(b == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if(b==1) {
            return a;
        }
        return a * mystery(a,b-1);
    }
```

e.g.,

`mystery(2, 6)` returns 64 as the result.

Comment: way to do someone else's homework for them

Answer (score 2):

Run it on paper:

mystery(10, 20)

b == 0 (false) b == 1 (false) so return 10 * mystery(10, 19)

mystery(10, 19)

boils down to return 10 * mystery(10, 18)

and so on.

Try with different values e.g. mystery(20, 10) mystery(5,5);